# Void' expects 2 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body

Tags: swift, firebase, closures

I'm trying to get the data of each child and assign the data I get to the variable named CoordinateAsil with the help of the struct. But when I code

```
self.KoordinatAsil = Koordinatlarlarimsi(koordinatx: koordinatX, koordinaty: koordinatY, width: Width, height: Height, differenceBetween: 0))
```

it gives me error

> Contextual closure type '(DataSnapshot, String?) -> Void' expects 2 arguments and value of type 'NSObject' has no member 'children'.

I also tried entering 2 arguments but it doesn't work.

```
struct Koordinatlarlarimsi{
    
    let koordinatx: Float
    let koordinaty: Float
    let width: Float
    let height: Float
    let differenceBetween: Float
}

class HaritaFirebaseVC: UIViewController {

    
    var database: DatabaseReference!
    var Koordinatciklar: [Koordinatlarlarimsi] = []
    var KoordinatAsil: Koordinatlarlarimsi?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        database = Database.database().reference()
        
        
        database.child("Harita").child("Pancarlar").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
            for case let child as DataSnapshot in snapshot.children{
                guard let dict = child.value as? [String:Any] else{
                    print("Error")
                    return
                }
                var koordinatX = dict["koordinatX"] as! Int
                var koordinatY = dict["koordinatY"] as! Int
                var Height = dict["Height"] as! Int
                var Width = dict["width"] as! Int

               
                 self.KoordinatAsil = Koordinatlarlarimsi(koordinatx: koordinatX, koordinaty: koordinatY, width: Width, height: Height, differenceBetween: 0)
                

                
            }
            
        }
```

[image]
...

Comment: If I read the error message correctly it should be `.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot, string) in ...`. You could also click on the error message to see what solution Xcode suggests.

Comment: "I also tried entering 2 arguments" No you didn't.

Comment: I wish all suggestions were correct in xcode. When I try solution, it gives me error that it is expected 1 argument but there is 2.

Comment: Then the two errors could perhaps mean that there is something wrong with the call `database.child("Harita").child("Pancarlar").observeSingleEvent(of: .value)`, maybe some Firebase expert can help you with this.

Comment: There are a number of issues in the question. First, the error shown at the top of the question is unrelated to the line of code above it. Second, the first line var doesn't match the text:  `CoordinateAsil' vs 'self.KoordinatAsil`. Third is there's an extra trailing ')' on that same line. Also, be careful with variable and node names `dict["Height"] as! Int` but I assume the actual structure node name is `height` so that line will crash because it's force-unwrapped `!`. Those appear to just be typos so check your actual code to ensure it's clean. Then, see the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The general issue is the implementation of the Firebase code. What you have is

```
database.child("Harita").child("Pancarlar").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
```

and it should be

```
database.child("Harita").child("Pancarlar").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
```

Note the `(.value, with: { snapshot in` which is the second parameter of the `.observeSingleEvent` function call

The closure needs to be part of the call for it to function correctly and will also fix the issue with the error `'NSObject' has no member 'children'.`

And I would also avoid casting everything to dictionaries. It will work but (IMO) this is more readable...

```
let allChildren = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
for snap in allChildren {
    let koordinatX = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "koordinatX").value as? Float ?? 0.0
```

...and provides a default value, protecting your code, in case the node is not found.